# Area of three points in 2d is equal to a determinant

Tags: math, computational-geometry

suppose we have a line segment(`pq`) and a point `r` close to it. How can I show that the area of the triangle `pqr` is equal to `|D|/2` :

if

```
          |1   px     py |
  D = det |1   qx     qy |
          |1   rx     ry |
```

`p=(px,py)`, `q=(qx,qy)`, `r=(rx,ry)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the vectors `PQ` and `PR`:

```
vector PQ = (qx-px, qy-py, 0)
vector PR = (rx-px, ry-py, 0)
```

The area of the triangle can be written in terms of `PQ` and `PR` using the [cross product formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Geometric_meaning):

```
Area = 1/2 |PR| · |PQ| · sin(theta)     # theta = included angle between PR and PQ
     = 1/2 |PR ⨯ PQ|
```

and this cross product can be written in terms of a determinant:

```
             |               |
2·Area = det |rx-px   ry-py   0|
             |qx-px   qy-py   0|

       = abs((rx-px)·(qy-py) - (qx-px)·(ry-py))

       = abs(rx·qy - rx·py - px·qy + px·py - qx·ry + qx·py + px·ry - px·py)
                                     ^^^^^                           ^^^^^
       = abs(rx·qy - rx·py - px·qy - qx·ry + qx·py + px·ry)
             ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^
             term1   term2   term3   term4   term5   term6
```

While on the other hand, the determinant you posted can also be expanded:

```
    |1   px   py |
det |1   qx   qy | = abs(qx·ry - rx·qy + rx·py - px·ry + px·qy - qx·py)
    |1   rx   ry |       ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^
                         term4   term1   term2   term6   term3   term5
```

So

```
             |1   px   py |
2·Area = det |1   qx   qy |
             |1   rx   ry |
```

Answer (score 1):

If by space you mean area, remember that the area of a triangle is base by height divided by two. The base can be the distance from p to q, an the height, the distance from the rect pq to point r. Write the equations down and you'll get it.